# Обрезать <link> js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется `<link>`, нужно `<link href="http://сайт.ру/odeyala/?filter_ocfilter=43:4078;42:484" rel="canonical" 1="">` обрезать ссылку, то есть `href="http://сайт.ру/odeyala/` получить такого вида `href`

```
$(function() {
    $("#aaa").each ( function() {
        alert ( $(this).attr ( "href" ).substring ($(this).attr ( "href" ).split('/?') ) );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По предыдущему комментарию, если правильно понял то будет:

```
$('#aaa').attr('href', $('#aaa').attr('href').split('/?') [0])
```

В вашем случае

```
$(function() {
    $("#aaa").each ( function() {
        alert ( $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').split('/?')[0]));
    });
});
```

Comment: спасибо!! то что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

`<link id="aaa" href="http://site/odeyala/?filter_ocfilter=43:4078;42:484" rel="canonical" 1="">`